# Switching from domain.com/post/ to domain.com/category/post/

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking to change the structure of permalinks on my site from from domain.com/post/ to domain.com/category/post/. what is the safest and best method to do that? do i have to do 301 redirects to each link manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention this earlier. I'm worried about the external links linking to my site; since changing permalinks structure will returns lots of 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your [Dashboard Permalink Settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags), change to a custom structure, like the following:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```